# Is it possible to make a proxy that can be inserted into a website through the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-proxy

I cant install any plugins or the proxy settings in Chrome but I am able to use the console. I have done the research to check through potential ways I could solve this and figured this is the best way, since I have to other way to add a proxy. I want to know if this is even possible and just where I should start looking. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Are you circumventing company's settings?

Comment: What kind of proxy are you thinking of? It might be possible to inject a service worker through js

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that is exactly what I was needing! You can post it as an answer so I could accept it if you want.

Comment: @PM 77-1 You guessed it! The only difference is that I'm in middle school, not a company.

Comment: Can you explain how a service worker could help circumventing middle school's settings?

Comment: Well, websites are blocked, so my logic is I redirect everything to an unblocked domain that I run some proxy server code on. I do know that its not quite this easy but I can figure it out from here. I already have a decent idea how I will make it, I just need to do a bunch of testing and start writing some code.

Comment: Yes, but how does a service worker help here? You wrote that that's exactly what you're looking for, but I have no clue how it solves your problem. If a website is blocked for the browser, it's also blocked for the service worker.

Comment: What I will do is send what website URL I need to open to my server, on an unblocked domain, which will send back all the HTML. I will then embed a service worker into the HTML, automatically, that will then act as a proxy. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#:~:text=A%20service%20worker%20functions%20like%20a%20proxy%20server%2C%20allowing%20you%20to%20modify%20requests%20and%20responses%20replacing%20them%20with%20items%20from%20its%20own%20cache.) documentation you can do that with service workers.